# Inline text- selecting variables from a table

Tags: r, r-markdown, kable

I have a table as follows:

```
table <- data.frame(number = 1:4, 
                    percentage2 = c(16, 79, 3, 3))
```

In R Markdown I would like to show the following output text:

```
At number 1 10% achieved
```

To do this I would normally amend the table like so:

```
table %>%
filter (number==1) -> tab
```

Then I would write into RMarkdown:

```
At number 1 `r (tab$percentage2)`% achieved.
```

Is there a way of achieving the same result without applying the filter to create 'tab'? I would have thought something like this would work but it doesn't.

```
At number 1 `r (tab$percentage2, number==1)`% achieved.
```

This is a very simple example of something that I do all the time so if there is a way without creating a new table by using a filter this will save me a lot of time.

Comment: I've reformatted your question to remove the picture of the data. This is bad practice and is a good way to attract downvotes. See the edit on how the data can easily be recreated with R code.

Comment: Okay noted. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

I don't see how this will save any time, but you can avoid creating the new table using

```
with(table, percentage2[which(number == 1)])
```

Comment: i see what you mean. Would there be a way of writing this into the text using `r (table$percentage)` rather than in the code chunk? otherwise I would need to write this in the chunk and then again in the text, which as you suggest wouldn't really save much time

Comment: You can put my expression in the text, it doesn't need to be in a code chunk.  It is just an expression that evaluates to the value you want.  Just use `table` instead of `tab`.  I've edited the answer to that now.

Comment: So in the text it would read At number 1 `r with(table, percentage2[which(number == 1)])`% achieved ? I've tried this but it doesn't seem to work

Answer (score 0):

It seems easiest to make a function to do the formatting for you. Here is a basic layout which you could customise for other scenarios:

```
displayresults <- function(df, num){
  paste0("Number ", number, " ", 
        with(table, percentage2[which(number == num)]),
        "% achieved")
}
```

Then by using:

```
`r displayresults(table, 1)`
```

will output

> ```
> Number 1 16% achieved
> ```

A complete example:

````
---
output: pdf_document
---

```{r}
table <- data.frame(number = 1:4, 
                    percentage2 = c(16, 79, 3, 3))


displayresults <- function(df, number){
  paste0("Number ", number, " ", 
        with(table, percentage2[which(number == 1)]),
        "% achieved")
}
```

`r displayresults(table, 1)`
````

Comment: You use `number` twice in that function:  once as an argument, once as a column name, and then ignore the arg.  You could change the arg name to `num`, and the `with()` statement to `with(table, percentage2[which(number == num)])` and it would work.  I don't know if it will be used more than once in the real document; if not, I probably wouldn't bother creating a function for it.

Comment: @user2554330 My bad, thanks for the heads up. The reason I suggested a function is that the question states "This is a very simple example of something that I do all the time", so though it might provide the asker with a technique which they could apply more generally.